# Hide and show options in a select list

Tags: jquery

I trying to hide some select list of `gp` id with onchange `block` id. But i can't. I wish to when `block` id's `value=127` select then hide all `gp` id's select list but excluding `gp` id's value `1427 to 1435`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#block").change(function() {

  var el = $(this) ;

  if(el.val() === "127" ) {
      $("#gp option").each(function(){
          if((this.value >= 1427) && (this.value <= 1435)){
         $(this).show();
            $("#gp option").hide();

          }
        });

    
 });

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="block">
   <option value="">--Select Block--</option>
  <option value="127">BAMANGOLA</option>
  <option value="128">CHANCHAL - I</option>
  <option value="129">CHANCHAL - II</option>
  </select>
  
<select id="gp">
<option value="">--Select Gram Panchayet--</option>
<option value="1440">SUJAPUR</option>
<option value="1439">SILAMPUR-II</option>
<option value="1438">SILAMPUR -I</option>
<option value="1437">NAWADA JADUPUR</option>
<option value="1436">MOZAMPUR</option>
<option value="1435">KALIA CHAK-II</option>
<option value="1434">KALIA CHAK-I</option>
<option value="1433">JALUA BADHAL</option>
<option value="1432">JALALPUR</option>
<option value="1431">GAYESHBARI</option>
<option value="1430">BAMANGRAM MOSIMPUR</option>
<option value="1429">ALIPUR-II</option>
<option value="1428">ALIPUR-I</option>
<option value="1427">ALINAGAR</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `data` attribute it'll be much easier to do that

- Add `data-block-start` and `data-block-end` to the options in the first `<select>` and use the same js code to `hide/show` the desired options in the second `<select>`

```js
$("#block").change(function() {
  var selected_option = $(this).find("option:selected");   //select the selected option
  var block_start = selected_option.data('block-start'); // get the block start number
  var block_end = selected_option.data('block-end'); // get the block end number
  $("#gp option").show().filter(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    return value < block_start || value > block_end;
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="block">
  <option value="">--Select Block--</option>
  <option value="127" data-block-start="1427" data-block-end="1435">BAMANGOLA</option>
  <option value="128" data-block-start="1436" data-block-end="1438">CHANCHAL - I</option>
  <option value="129" data-block-start="1433" data-block-end="1440">CHANCHAL - II</option>
</select>

<select id="gp">
  <option value="">--Select Gram Panchayet--</option>
  <option value="1440">SUJAPUR</option>
  <option value="1439">SILAMPUR-II</option>
  <option value="1438">SILAMPUR -I</option>
  <option value="1437">NAWADA JADUPUR</option>
  <option value="1436">MOZAMPUR</option>
  <option value="1435">KALIA CHAK-II</option>
  <option value="1434">KALIA CHAK-I</option>
  <option value="1433">JALUA BADHAL</option>
  <option value="1432">JALALPUR</option>
  <option value="1431">GAYESHBARI</option>
  <option value="1430">BAMANGRAM MOSIMPUR</option>
  <option value="1429">ALIPUR-II</option>
  <option value="1428">ALIPUR-I</option>
  <option value="1427">ALINAGAR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with `.show().filter().hide()` and the opposite `.filter()`  because in the previous code if you change the first `<select>` to any option then return back to `Select Block` option the second `<select>` options will remain `hide()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this context on hiding the options

```js
$("#block").change(function() {

  var el = $(this);


  if (el.val() === "127") {
    $("#gp option").each(function(i, v) {
      if (($(v).val() >= 1427) && ($(v).val() <= 1435)) {

        $(v).hide();

      }
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="block">
  <option value="">--Select Block--</option>
  <option value="127">BAMANGOLA</option>
  <option value="128">CHANCHAL - I</option>
  <option value="129">CHANCHAL - II</option>
</select>

<select id="gp">
  <option value="">--Select Gram Panchayet--</option>
  <option value="1440">SUJAPUR</option>
  <option value="1439">SILAMPUR-II</option>
  <option value="1438">SILAMPUR -I</option>
  <option value="1437">NAWADA JADUPUR</option>
  <option value="1436">MOZAMPUR</option>
  <option value="1435">KALIA CHAK-II</option>
  <option value="1434">KALIA CHAK-I</option>
  <option value="1433">JALUA BADHAL</option>
  <option value="1432">JALALPUR</option>
  <option value="1431">GAYESHBARI</option>
  <option value="1430">BAMANGRAM MOSIMPUR</option>
  <option value="1429">ALIPUR-II</option>
  <option value="1428">ALIPUR-I</option>
  <option value="1427">ALINAGAR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I want if 127 is selected than show only 1427 to 1435 values